# Power of X Calculation On Ubuntu (10.4)

Tags: ubuntu

On a typical Ubuntu (10.4 in this case) desktop how can I do "to the power of" or "exponent" calculations?

So for example I want to know 2^80, Google calculator shows "2^80 = 1.20892582 × 1024" and I'm too lazy to type all my sums in there and then convert them to the full answer.

I have bash (bc/expr), C & C++ installed, as well as a browser so I have JavaScript at my disposal, and I have php-cli installed.

I must be able to use on of these via the command line to perform the exponent sums like a calculator? Just parsing the sum as a one liner?

Everything I do comes out as the abbreviated answer like Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really on topic, but

```
echo "2^80" | bc
```

Comment: I'd say it is dude! You've done it :D I've got a fair few to do so this is perfect I can pipe them all in. Thanks so much, It won't let me mark this as correct yet it's too soon, but I will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -e 'printf("%f", 2**80)'
1208925819614629174706176.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dc` (it should already be installed; otherwise, install the "dc" package). It is a calculator which uses a postfix syntax:

```
$ dc
2 80 ^ p
1208925819614629174706176
```

`man dc` for details. Among noteworthy details:

- `dc` can do floating-point computations with configurable precision (see the `k` command);
- `dc` can convert between basis (e.g. hexadecimal);
- there is a *modular exponentiation* operator (the `|`) which is very handy when doing cryptography-related operations.